# cant make arm project in ubuntu : " undefined reference to__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi "

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, arm

I downloaded this http://code.google.com/p/qcombbdbg/  src/preloader get compiled but cant compile  src/qcombbdbg

```
maysam@ubuntu:~/Desktop/QDebugger/src/qcombbdbg$ make
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -Bstatic -x -X -Map qcombbdbg.map  -T devices/qcombbdbg-2.5.23Hd.script qcombbdbg.o rex.o interrupts.o mmu.o core.o trace.o relocator.o -o qcombbdbg.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: warning: section `.bss' type changed to PROGBITS
trace.o: In function `trace_vm_exec':
/home/maysam/Desktop/QDebugger/src/qcombbdbg/trace.c:840: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
relocator.o: In function `relocate_thumb_insn':
/home/maysam/Desktop/QDebugger/src/qcombbdbg/relocator.c:920: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uhi'
/home/maysam/Desktop/QDebugger/src/qcombbdbg/relocator.c:1336: undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
make: *** [link] Error 1
maysam@ubuntu:~/Desktop/QDebugger/src/qcombbdbg$
```

What can I do to fix these errors?